# How to open DevTools from code in WebView2?

Tags: c#, winforms, devtools, webview2

With the newly released WebView2, is it possible to open the DevTools from code (WinForms)?

I want to automatically show the DevTools (console) on Javascript errors.

Answer (score 3):

Just call the method OpenDevToolsWindow() of the ICoreWebView2 Interface.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-1.0.664.37#opendevtoolswindow

Answer (score 2):

Just to add that the CoreWebView2 have to be initalized before use :

```
<wv2:WebView2
        Name="webView"
        Source="https://www.microsoft.com" />

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    public async void Init()
    {
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        webView.CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow();
    }
}
```